# postgresql 9.4 streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have the following problem: i am trying to set up a streaming replication scenario with load balancing. I read various tutorials but i cannot find the mistake. The replication does not work. I do not have a "wal sender/receiver process". The archiving works and everytime the master restarts, the archived wal files are copied to the slave. I even do not get any error. And in configuration file(s) everything looks like fine for me, e.g. master:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
wal_keep_segments = 32
max_wal_senders = 5
max_replication_slots = 5
wal_sender_timeout = 60s
```

What irritates me the most is that there is no "wal sender process" and there is no error thrown.

Thank you for any idea,
Sven

UPDATE 1: my recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=arcserver1 port=5432 user=postgres pass=postgres'
restore_command = 'pg_standby /db/pg_archived %f %p >> /var/log/standby.log'
primary_slot_name='standby1'
```

and my client postgresql.conf contains:

```
hot_standby = on
```

Comment: Have you `restore.conf` config on slave machine? Show us both `postgresql.conf` and `restore.conf` of your slave.

Comment: i guess you mean recovery.conf, yes it is there. i updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: This question really belongs on serverfault so i will add a comment instead of answering. Manual replication sucks. Start using repmgr it's an open source product that makes streaming replication really easy.

Comment: @Sven jest I mean `recovery.conf`. I'm right now using `pg_restore` and that's source of error:)

Comment: @Sven Could you post `archive_command` from your master's `postgresql.conf`. What I see is you trying to setup logshiping by WAL archiving. `wal_sender` process is used by steaming replication which is slightly  different aproach.

Comment: @Sven also try to change your restore_command to `'pg_standby /db/pg_archived -d %f %p >> /var/log/standby.log 2>&1'` `-d` will write more debbuging messages to `stderr` and `2>&1` redirects all system streams to your stanby.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:i replaced pg_standby with cp, because pg_standby seems to be only for warm standby, not hot standby.